# Kedro documentation does not show up all functions after compiling kedro build-docs

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, kedro

I tried documenting my project using `kedro build-docs` command.

```
.
├── docs
└── src
    ├── setup.py
    ├── tests
    ├── <project>
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __main__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── a
    │   ├── hooks.py
    │   ├── pipeline_registry.py
    │   ├── pipelines
    │   │   └── pipeline.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── b
    │   └── c
    |_
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are different modules inside project and I am trying to document using sphinx. I compiled `kedro build-docs` command in terminal and it generates `.rst` files inside the `docs` directory and creates `docs/build/**/index.html` file. Upon opening this I find all my modules listed as hyperlink, and upon going inside `a` module, I find not all functions were documented.
For example if I have 3 functions listed inside module `a` , the html shows up only 2 and rest are not shown up on html page.
Need help to show up all functions doc strings.

Comment: Without a [mcve], it's hard to help.

Comment: I want to set `autodoc_default_flags` in conf.py, I am facing difficulty

Comment: You need to provide more information. What specific difficulty are you facing?